# Shell attempts to interpret Perl script in spite of correct shebang

Tags: linux, solaris, perl, shebang

I have looked through the forums and I can't seem to find how to fix this. I have a very simple perl code that works fine on Windows, but when I try it on Linux and Solaris I get the following errors:

```
bash: ./test.pl: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: ./test.pl: line 2: `print '$_\n' for @Config{qw(myuname osname osvers)};'
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Config;
use strict;
print '$_\n' for @Config{qw(myuname osname osvers)};
```

Any thoughts on how I can get around this?

Comment: Are you missing a leading `/` on the shebang line, so it's `#!/usr/bin/perl` or is that just a typo?

Comment: I have tried that but am still getting the same error. Not sure why it does not want to pick up the perl compiler

Comment: Does your file by any chance have windows-ish linebreaks?  `cat -v test.pl` will show you that.

Comment: Does not look like it. I got it working by entering /usr/bin/perl test.pl

Comment: What operating system are you using? What is the exact script (newline convention, `#!/usr/bin/perl` or `#!usr/bin/perl`, etc.)? What does `file -L /usr/bin/perl` say? Whatever problem you're having, it's due to something you aren't telling us.

Comment: How are you calling it? You're not doing `bash ./test.pl` are you?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue. I am on Solaris 10 and Linux 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following into your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Also, I didn't see the path of your Perl on the machine
like `/usr/bin/perl` at the beginning of the code.
You can see the correct form from the shell command prompt by using `which perl`.

Comment: I have updated my code above. I have tried to include which compiler to use but am still getting the same error :(
when i type in ' whereis perl ' it shows perl: /usr/bin/perl /opt/perl5.8.4/bin/perl /usr/share/man/man1/perl.1.gz

Comment: what is the output from which perl command ?

Comment: when using 'which perl' it shows /usr/bin/perl

Comment: make test with only for example print blblblba and with #!usr/bin/perl in the beggining just to check if perl workaing at all

Comment: Looks like it works if I say /usr/bin/perl test.pl.
Not sure why it does not want to work if I enter it in the top of the .pl file. Thanks!

Comment: if I were you, I wouldn't have mentioned `use strict; use warnings;`. this is because it is only tangentially related to the original question. you could have kept it if you want, but _mention_ that it doesn't matter all that much from the point of view of OP.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/perl`) isn't interpreted on your system because `bash` itself is trying to interpret the script. Try invoking the script as:

```
[user@host]$ perl test.pl
```

Also, a much better "shebang" line courtesy of the [Camel book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000271.do):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
eval "exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}"
    if $running_under_some_shell;
```

This allows you to invoke the script as `./test.pl` regardless of whether your system understands the shebang line.

**Additional note**

This is not related to the actual issue, but it's an issue you'll eventually run into when you get Perl to interpret your script: `'$_\n'` is wrong, you need interpolative quotes (also called soft quotes and double quotes) for `$_` to be interpolated and `\n` to be recognized as an escape sequence as opposed to a literal backslash preceding the letter `n`.

Several ways you can do this:

```
print "$_\n"   for @Config{...}
```

or

```
print qq{$_\n} for @Config{...}
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
...
print for @Config{...}
```

or (requires Perl 5.10 or higher)

```
use feature qw(say)
...
say for @Config{...}
```

Comment: I have tried that but am still getting the same error. Not sure why it does not want to pick up the perl compiler :(

Comment: @user974873 What do you get with `file /usr/bin/perl`?

Comment: Interesting. Seems to work this way but not when I reference it in the .pl file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, `bash` is trying to execute your script instead of `perl`. You can also try using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Instead of your current shebang to see if `perl` picks it up.